# Why did the Chachamim change this Passuk?

Tags: talmud-gemara, tanach, rashi, creation, tractate-megillah

The [Gemara](https://www.themercava.com/app/books/metanav/12595) brings in the incident of a king gathering 72 sages to translate the Torah to Greek. They all came with the idea to change some Psukim. One of them was

> זָכָ֥ר וּנְקֵבָ֖ה **בְּרָאָ֑ם** וַיְבָ֣רֶךְ אֹתָ֗ם וַיִּקְרָ֤א אֶת
> ־שְׁמָם֙ אָדָ֔ם בְּי֖וֹם הִבָּֽרְאָֽם
> He created them male and
> female; He blessed **them** and called their name Adam, on the day they
> were created.

The Sages changed it to

> זָכָר וּנְקֵבָה **בְּרָאוֹ**
>
> 'Male and female, he created **him**'

Why?

Rashi says it is to show that they were made conjoined, and Hashem split them. But what is the big deal if they think they were made separate?

Comment: I wonder of there's a connection to Plato's myth of the androgynous (Plato, one of the greatest of the Greek philosophers, brought in *Symposium* a legend that humans were created conjoined and later separated).

Comment: R Steinsaltz explains it was to avoid the impression that there is a contradiction between this verse and the verse: “And God created man” (Genesis 1:27), which indicates that God created one person. https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.9a.13

Comment: Rashi's comment is not meant to explain the deviation but to explain why the contradiction that motivated the deviation need not trouble us.

Comment: @Harel13 the speech of Aristophanes has a more convoluted path to sexual dimorphism than the midrash repeated by Rashi.  In his myth there were originally double men, double women and man-woman combos. Zeus split all three types, thus creating heterosexuals, homosexual men and homosexual women.

Comment: @MosheWise I'm familiar. How is that contradictory?

Comment: @Harel13 who said there is a contradiction? I am simply pointing out that the Aristophanes speech is actually quite different from the midrash in its details and purpose even though both stories do discuss double-beings later being split into single beings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Talmud is saying that the translators were worried that leaving the text as is would create a contradiction between Genesis 5.1, where the creator creates a single being (hence the singular עשה אתו) and Genesis 5.2, where the creator creates multiple beings (hence the plural בראם). To avoid this contradiction they changed Genesis 5.2 to singular.